# How can I use git to manage a vended product's configuration files (or is there a more appropriate tool)?

Tags: git, configuration-files

I support a vended piece of software with literally thousands of configuration files under our control. We run this software in a production/pre-production/development set of environments. The software is made up of 5 modules on the client side, and server-side is shared among 4 institutions with each institution having its own configuration tree, plus a shared set of configuration files. Many of these configuration files only impact a small handful of processes related to a single module for a single institution. At any given time, we may have many multiple different modifications being tested, each with a limited scope. It's very rare for these to have impact on each other, based on the way the software is architected.

In an attempt to get better control over these files, we've put the entire config tree into a git repository.  We started off creating a single master branch based on production, and tried pushing files up from pre-production when ready to go to production, and then pulling them down.  The issue has been that we often make changes directly in production, which also get pushed up, and the two servers get out of sync.  Both servers' working copies are the live files.

I tried creating separate branches for each server, but I've run into an issue here where we could be testing multiple changes in completely unrelated systems at any given time, but only want to migrate specific changes to production individually, when each has been tested and tweaked and ready to go.

The best solution I've come up with so far is not committing any changes until it's ready to be pushed to production, and then only committing the files (and even cherry-picking sections of files) when ready to deploy to production.  The downside to this is current working changes in pre-prod aren't committed anywhere, and an inappropriate git command could wipe them out without a recovery option (ignoring routine backups, which won't cover intra-day changes but would help with critical multi-day testing configurations).

Is there a better solution for managing all these config files, either with git or something else?

Comment: Trying to bump this.  We're working on a modified workflow involving BitBucket and pull requests, but I'm hoping someone has some tips on how to best approach this (or what not to do)